# How do I switch from One Nib/Storyboard to another Nib/Storyboard?

Tags: uistoryboard, swift2, xcode7-beta5

Environnment: 
Xcode 7.0/Swift 2.0 for iOS 9 platform.

Scenario: 
I disseminated my large UIStoryboard object into four smaller UIStoryboards; each storyboard link to its respective tab:

[image]

I want to link from one member scene/storyboard to a different scene/storyboard.

Hence, I instantiated a target UIViewController/Nib or 'scene' within a different UIStoryboard upon request:

```
let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in
gStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "(2.0)Discovery", bundle: nil)

let controller = gStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(kDiscoveryCreateTag) as! DiscoveryCreateViewController
print(controller)
}
```

This code appears to be okay... I got the target controller.  I attempted to instantiate it and got a controller variable point to my target controller; but I *still remain in the source* UIViewController, as if nothing happened.  I'm lost what to do from here.

What am I missing here?

Note: I want to make a clean jump to the other storyboard's scene vs being a presented view controller.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: I ended up having to reverse myself thru the storyboard.  I would get a runtime error if I don't follow this:   "Unbalanced calls to begin/end Appearance Transitions".  Hence I had to hide my path (bypassing UI display) en route to my target & return.   On hindsight, I may have been better to handle this manually vs storyboard to avoid the internal baggage that UIStoryboard's segues have.